# (REGEX) Replace with empty when two <br> appear in a string PHP

Tags: php, regex

i have differents strings may be can:

1 Case

```
<br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br><br>Text<br><br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br><br><br>{text}";
```

2 Case

```
<br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br><br>Text<br><br>{text}<br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}";
```

3 Case

```
{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br><br>Text<br><br>{text}<br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br><br><br>Text";
```

I'm try to limit to

```
<br><br>
```

In cases if have found 3 or more continue

```
<br>
```

With the php code:

```
preg_replace("/<br>\s+(?=<br>)/", "", $adContent);
```

Expected cases:

1 Case

```
<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>Text<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}";
```

2 Case

```
<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>Text<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}";
```

3 Case

```
{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>Text<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>Text";
```

Used regex:

```
/<br>\s+(?=<br>)/
```

Testing: https://paiza.io/projects/sLcZE5fW99p3gfrxaZGDsg

Thanks

My Regex not working

Comment: Why not post this question [using your original account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5293540/alfinoide) ?

Comment: I have reach the limit asks

Comment: There is a reason for a limit. You've asked 9 questions and only one has a positive score or an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace *three* or more `<br>` tags with just two tags, then use:

```php
$input = "{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br><br>Text<br><br>{text}<br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br>{text}<br><br><br><br><br><br>Text";
$output = preg_replace("/(?:<br>){3,}/", "<br><br>", $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>Text<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>{text}<br><br>Text
```

Comment: Hi Tim, just working in the first group but not in all string.

Comment: My code is working in PHP.  I don't know what the problem is.